# Simple Event Handling in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Just wondering what people had for ideas on how best to handle events in a ViewModel from controls on a View ... in the most lightweight way possible.

Example:

```
<MediaElement
     MediaOpened={Binding SomeEventHandler} />
```

In this case we want to handle the MediaOpened event in a ViewModel.  Without a framework like Prism, how would one bind this to a ViewModel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Commanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) - your 'SomeEventHandler' needs to be a class that implements `ICommand`... there's a heap of literature available online...

Also - I would consider getting a free, lightweight 'mini' MVVM framework, such as [MvvmFoundation](http://www.codeplex.com/mvvmfoundation), which provides the RelayCommand for just such a purpose (without the complexity/overhead of learning PRISM)

**EDIT:**

Have a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201027180030/http://geekswithblogs.net/HouseOfBilz/archive/2009/08/27/adventures-in-mvvm-ndash-binding-commands-to-any-event.aspx) blog for attaching command to any event... It is incredibly powerful, as I mentioned, but I guess you do need to make a judgement call if this is what you want, compared with something like attaching an old-fashioned event, and using a super-slim event handler in your code behind that simply invokes some method on your ViewModel, something like:

```
public void SomeEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)this.DataContext;
    vm.HandleLoadEvent( );
}
```

pragmatic vs Best-practise... I'll leave it with you ;)

Comment: I didn't think I could use an ICommand in this sort of scenario ... thanks for the info ... this is a bit of a repeat question then.

Comment: Ok ... I just tried using the ICommand, I'm using MVVMFoundation, so it's a RelayCommand type.  However, I get a build error "Binding Path=MediaOpenedCommand, Mode=OneTime}' is not a valid event handler method name ..."   Am I just setting it up wrong?

Comment: sorry, yes... you will need to bind the RelayCommand instance to a Command, and tie this back to the UI via CommandBindings or InputBindings... I strongly recommend you do a wee bit of reading - switching from events to commands is one of those "steep learning curves" that people keep on about with WPF - but so powerful when you grok it!!

Comment: I get Command binding when you have a "Command" property on controls like ... Button, Hyperlink, etc.  I can't find any examples or explanations on creating a Command property on a control that can handle something like the example above.  I get that I need to bind the RelayCommand to a "Command" ... but how do I create a command on something like the MediaElement that can execute my ICommand when the Source has loaded (equivalent to when the MediaOpened event would fire).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Marlon Grech's [Attached Command Behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/). It makes it easy to bind events to ViewModel commands

Answer (score 0):

MediaOpened is an event and does not support command binding.

In order to bind to the event a helper object may be used which attaches to the event and executes a command.

To bind to the view model add a property which implements ICommand. Figure 3 in this MSDN magazine article shows the RelayCommand which is a useful implementation of ICommand. RelayCommand is initialized with a delegate to connect to your view model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: I get the Command Binding issue and I've read Josh Smith's article on MVVM, but the part I'm having a problem with is the 
"to bind to the event a helper object may be used which attaches to the event and executes a command".
By helper object do you mean like an Attached Behavior?

Comment: Yes, a Behavior is a good way to make the binding.  The link that IanR provided looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The small and opensource [ImpromptuInterface.MVVM](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ImpromptuInterface.MVVM) framework ha an [event binding syntax](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageMVVMAdvanced#Event_Binding) and using the dlr in .net 4.0. Although this example requires subclassing the ImpromptuViewModel. The [event binding  property](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface.MVVM/src/ImpromptuViewModel.cs#136) doesn't have any dependency on that specific viewmodel type and the [eventbinding provider](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface.MVVM/src/Event.cs#208) involved is public.

```
 <Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MVVM="clr-namespace:ImpromptuInterface.MVVM;assembly=ImpromptuInterface.MVVM" Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">

  <MediaElement MVVM:Event.Bind="{Binding Events.MediaOpened.To[MediaElement_MediaOpened]}"  />
```

...

```
public class MyViewModel{

    public dynamic Events
    {
        get { return new EventBinder(this); }
    }

    public void MediaElement_MediaOpened(MediaElement sender,   RoutedEventArgs e){
         ...
    }
}
```