# Binding to a method wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have in my xaml view file  `<TabControl  AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragOver="{Binding Path=DragOver}" PreviewDrop="Drop">`

The `DragOver` function located in the `ViewModel.cs` class .

and I am getting following error

```
PreviewDragOver="{Binding Path=DragOver}" is not valid. '{Binding Path=DragOver}' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.
```

What is wrong in the way how i try bind to a function ?
How It should be ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926176/simple-event-handling-in-mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only bind to properties in your viemmodel and in case you need to invoke any function from your viemodel you need to do it through routed commands. For starting how to implement commands take a look at these links, they might help -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx (1)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx (2)

Comment: but how I can pass  the DragEventArgs from the view to the Relay command ?

Answer (score 0):

The `PreviewDragDrop` is an event just like the `PreviewDrop`, and it expects to get an appropriate event handler. If `DragOver` is the event handler, then your code should look like `<TabControl AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragOver="DragOver" PreviewDrop="Drop">`

Comment: when I have this event handler in code behind of the xaml I have no problems , but i move to the viewmodel class i get this error