# How to handle a listbox keydown event in the viewmodel?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-controls, binding

I have a listbox how do i handle the keydown event in the corresponding view model of the page ?

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to handle the keydown event?

Comment: i need to handle a listbox key down event in the view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related: [Simple Event Handling in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926176/simple-event-handling-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

you have to register your method in the properties panel. onItemClickListener, something like that.